# How should I transport a few cubic meters from TLV airport to where I live?

Tags: rental, relocation, car, israel

I'm moving to Israel/Palestine (actually, in my case it's moving back, but it's a part of the cycle of expat life I guess.) I'm flying a few cubic meters of stuff from where I was living before, and it's going to get to the Ben-Gurion airport (TLV), and I'll need to come there and release it.

We're talking about cardboard and plastic boxes, some with fragile contents, but nothing that's oddly-shaped, and no dimension is longer than 1 meter, nor any box larger than 0.15 m^3.

My question: What are the most cost-effective ways to transport these boxes from the airport to some city (e.g. Haifa)? Specifically, is there some kind service available within the "airport city" that's worthwhile to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is renting a van. You would need either an Israeli driver's license in the appropriate category for the van's weight/size, or to rent from somewhere that offers a van+driver combination. Look for something like "השכרת טנדר ליום" ("Rent a van for a day") on search engines.

Issues:

- This is not cheap; for a full day you could well pay over 500 NIS.
- Many (most?) places will expect you to return the van to where you got it, which means going back-and-forth twice (unless you rent it at the same city you're transporting your boxes to).
- You don't actually need the van for a day, just for several hours. Unfortunately, it's difficult to determine in advance exactly how long you need the van for.
- It may not be trivial to select the exact vehicle to rent in order to fit your boxes. I can't quite find listings of effective internal volume, and even then - you might have quite a bit of "dead space".